# type error using ctypes with windows dll function

Tags: ctypes

nl5 is a windows dll that includes a function with following prototype:

```
int NL5_Open(char* name)
```

I am trying to open a file "opamp_impulse_response" with the following Python3 code:

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_int, c_char_p, c_double

nl5_lib = "C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Desktop/nl5/nl5_dll/nl5_dll_64"
nl5 = cdll.LoadLibrary(nl5_lib)

nl5.NL5_Open.argtypes = [c_char_p] 
nl5.NL5_Open.restype = c_int
oa_file = "C:/User/andre/OneDrive/Desktop/nl5/opamp_impulse_response" 
ncir = nl5.NL5_Open(oa_file) 
ncir
```

I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d82b34e88c87> in <module>
      2 nl5.NL5_Open.restype = c_int
      3 oa_file = "C:/User/andre/OneDrive/Desktop/nl5/opamp_impulse_response"
----> 4 ncir = nl5.NL5_Open(oa_file)
      5 ncir

ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Can you tell me what is the type error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `'string'` is a Unicode string and ctypes translates it to `c_wchar_p` (wchar_t* in C).

Use `b'string'` for a byte string that corresponds to `c_char_p` (char* in C).

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Yes your answer eliminated the type error.  The call to the DLL now returns an error indicating the file can't be found or can't be opened.  Could this be a difference in how the DLL function is encoded versus how Python3 expects it to be encoded? (the path is correct and the file is not corrupted)

Comment: @Andy Not likely given your string is ASCII. You can use a tool looked SysInternals Process Monitor to see exactly what the OS receives as a path.

Comment: You mean my path string "C:/ ... opamp_impulse_response" is ascii, and you expect the DLL to handle that correctly?  I was suspecting something related to UTF-8 encoding -- since I believe this to be the Python3 default, I thought I may need to ensure that the DLL and the Python program are speaking the same I/O language..  (thanks for tip on process monitor, I'll check that out)

Comment: @Andy yes, an ASCII-encoded string is also a correctly encoded UTF-8 string, so a byte string of all ASCII characters is valid UTF-8 as well. Only code points >127 could cause trouble.  Windows APIs generally expect an ANSI-encoded string (legacy localized encoding...Windows-1252 for US and Western European countries) but ASCII is also a valid subset of that encoding as well.

Comment: great, I understand -- this helps me a lot, thank you -- Andy